# GEE Filter Date for Time ranges

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am not right into GEE.
So I want to create a NDVI with comparing 2 timeranges.
Actually from 2020-03-01 to 2020-10-01 AND 2021-03-01 to 2021-10-01.
So I want to exclude winter season.

I am using this Code below.
How do I have to change it for working?

```
var s2 = Images
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10)
.filterDate ('2020-03-01', '2020-10-01')
.filterBounds (geometry);
```

Comment: How do you wish to compare 2 time range? If you want to include specific time range, you can use [merge](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-merge)

Comment: I may specify. Actually I want the NDVI of 2020-03-01 to 2021-10-01 without the winter months